# Null pointer exception Portlet , class not found exception Dispatcher Servlet & ViewResolverServlet while deploying project using maven in liferay

Tags: spring-mvc

I  have configured disaptcher servlet,portlet class and Internal view resolver in portlet.xml, [portlet-name]-portlet.xml and web.xml respectively. but still i am getting errors

Comment: Web.xml<web-app ..">
 <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/portlet-application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: portlet.xml
<portlet-...">
 <portlet>
  <portlet-name>Test</portlet-name>
  <display-name>Test</display-name>
  <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
   <value>/WEB-INF/portlet-xml/test-portlet.xml</value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <name>add-process-action-success-action</name>
   <value>false</value>
  </init-param> 
  <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
  <supports>
   <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </supports>

Comment: [portlet-name]-portlet.xml
<beans  ....">
 <context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.* " />
 <bean id="Testcontroller" class="com.controller.Testcontroller" />
 <bean id="portletModeHandlerMapping"
  class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.PortletModeHandlerMapping">
  <property name="portletModeMap">
   <map>
<entry key="view">
<ref bean="Testcontroller" />
</entry>
</map>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>